# PMF does not sum to $1$ - Process NGINAR(1)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, time-series, discrete-time

I have the following PMF:
\begin{equation}
  P(\alpha^{(k)} \ast x = r) = 
  \begin{cases}
    A_{k}^{x}, & \text{if $r = 0$}.\\
    \frac{1}{r} \sum_\limits{l=1}^{r}{l{r \choose l}A_{k}^{x-1}B_{k}^{l}C_{k}^{r-1}{x \choose l}}, & \text{if $r \geq 1$},
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $A_k = \frac{1 - \alpha^{k}}{1 - \alpha^{k+1}}$, $B_k = \frac{\alpha^{k}(1-\alpha)^2}{(1-\alpha^{k+1})^2}$, and $C_k = \frac{\alpha(1-\alpha^{k})}{1-\alpha^{k+1}}$.

$r$, $k$, and  $x$ are all integers and $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

For fixed $\alpha$ and $k$, if $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, the PMF sum to $1$ when we vary $r$ ($r = 0, 1, 2,\ldots$). However, when $x>1$, the PMF does not sum to $1$. I checked this computationally, but I need to obtain a formal proof.

Source:

Awale, M., Ramanathan, T. V., and Kale, M. 2017. Coherent forecasting in integer-valued AR(1) models with geometric marginals. Journal of Data Science 15:95–114.

Comment: A formal proof of what, exactly?

Comment: A proof that this formula, for $x>1$, is a proper PMF or a counterexample showing that it is not the case.